# VisualStudio Code marks error in React code to close html tag

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run basic React helloworld application under VisualStudio Code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();

var element = < h1 > abcd < /h1>;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I run it in commandline everything works fine, but I wonder why VisualStudio Code marks error at line: (after save)

```
var element = < h1 > abcd < /h1>;
```

And claims, that opened tag should be closed.

Here is my configuration (as I suppose it is IDE specific issue)

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": { "javascript": "jsx" }
}
```

When I google for solution, all answers just say to only add closing html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply you are adding unnecessary white space:

```
var element = < h1 > abcd < /h1>; // BAD
var element = <h1>abcd</h1>; // GOOD :)
```

I strongly recommend to keep it as a good practice to avoid adding those extra spaces, it makes it hard for your editor to parse it as actual `HTML/JSX`. I am using VSCode as well and it doesn't even recognize it as proper `JSX` if I use spaces like in your example.

Comment: Great answer, but VSCode inserts them automatically after save (Ctrl+S)

Comment: It adds the spaces automatically after save ? It might be that you are missing the jsx, babel plugin.

Comment: Try removing the `emmet` config, and then check if you have plugins that might cause this issue, you can try deactivate some of them and see if it happens again.

Comment: Disabling autoindent fixed the issue, I will investigate what was real root cause some other time. Thank you for tips!